# cursor new line positioning with Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

How can I set default cursor position after new line to column=1 in Notepad++?
By default the cursor starts with offset matching all whitespace characters at the beginning of previous (non-empty) line, but I would like to ignore this clever alignment.

There is possible way to use replace with regex, but permanent solution would be much more appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uncheck the `Auto-indent` option found at:

Settings => Preferences => MISC.